# Existence of a monochromatic isosceles triangle when all the points on the circumference of the circle is coloured red, blue, or green.

Tags: combinatorics

All the points in a circle are coloured red, blue, or green. Prove that there exists a monochromatic isosceles triangle.

If the question had specified to use only two colours then the solution could be achieved by considering a regular pentagon inscribed in the circle. Then at least 3 of the points must be of the same colour (by Pigeonhole principle). There is no way to pick 3 of the points without them forming an isosceles triangle.

But with 3 distinct colours I am not able to find out how many sided regular polygon is required to achieve the solution. I have considered upto a regular decagon but still not able to confirm the existence of a monochromatic isosceles triangle with 3 distinct colours.

I found a more generic problem while searching the internet in the process of solving or at https://books.google.co.in/
CRUX 817     by Stanley Rabinowitz

(b) Prove that there are monochromatic isosceles triangles if to every point on the circumference of a circle we arbitrarily assign one of k colors, k >= 2.

We have to find at least one monochromatic isosceles triangle for k >= 2.

It seems there may be well identified logic to solve the problem for k >= 2.

I have also determined the following fact while trying to solve the given problem for k = 3.

If I consider an n sided regular polygon inscribed in a circle then there are n*floor((n - 1)/2) number of isosceles triangles formed by joining the vertices when n is not divisible by 3 and n*floor((n - 1)/2) - (2/3)*n isosceles triangles when n is divisible by 3.

Please help me out to be aware on how to solve for k = 3 and then for any positive number of colours k.

Thanks a lot in anticipation. Please help me out.

High Regards,
Shamik Banerjee
B. Tech. from IIT Kharagpur, 1998

Comment: Are you familiar with Ramsey Theory? In particular, existence of arithmetic progressions when coloring $\mathbb{N}$ with $k$ colors.

Comment: I guessed van der Warden's theorem in Ramsey Theory would provide the solution but I am not considerably aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use Ramsey Theory, Van Der Waerden's theorem.

> For $k$ colors and $m$ integers, there is a $ N(k,m)$ such that if the first $n \geq N(k,m)$ integers are colored with $k$ colors, then a $m$-term monochromatic arithmetic progression exists.

Corollary: Consider the vertices of a regular $ N (k,3)-$gon colored with $k$ colors. There exists a monochromatic isosceles triangle in it.

Note: The proof of this theorem requires some work, and I'm not going to reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have gone through https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem to realise that W(2, 3) = 9 (corresponding to the regular pentagon in my original post) and W(3, 3) = 27. So, a 27 sided regular polygon would definitely generate a monochromatic isosceles triangle in the circle with 3 choice of colours. I am trying to find out if n can be made less than 27 because of the cyclic symmetry. Please, let me know if you get it.  High Regards, Shamik Banerjee

Comment: It possibly could due to the relaxation of restrictions. Haven't thought about that much, because the existence is much more interesting than trying to find a lower bound.

Comment: In writing "$m$-term arithmetic progression exists" you left out the word "monochromatic".

Comment: If you only need it for $3$ colors, it's probably easier to run the backtrack algorithm than to prove Van der Waerden's theorem.

Comment: @user14111 Thanks edited. Can you write up your solution via the backtrack algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

$13-$gon works for the circular case.
In fact, this is one of Turkish MO 1998 problems.
See: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h421458p2381006